# Creating a Q promise and invoking it later

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise, q

I'm trying to create a dialog box system in typescript.

The intended use would be that a caller would do something like this;

```
dialogBox.showDialog().then((result: DialogResult) => {
    // Handle the dialog result
});
```

My `DialogBox` class would probably have some methods like this;

```
private promise : Q.Promise<DialogResult>; 

public showDialog() : Q.Promise<DialogResult>{
    this.promise = ... // How to create this promise?

    return this.promise;
}

public void setResult(result : DialogResult){
    // What to do here?
}
```

Whenever the user clicks a button in the dialog, something like this would be called;

```
dialogBox.setResult(theResult);
```

This should then resolve/fulfill the promise created by the `showDialog` method.

But I can't really figure out if this is possible with Q and so, how to implement the (promise-related parts of) `showDialog` and `setResult`. Anyone got any ideas?

**Update for completeness**; Thanks to Bergi, here's my final, working code. Ended up using a deferred

```
export class DialogBox implements INotification {
    private deferred: Q.Deferred<DialogResult>; 

    constructor(public message: string,
                public header: string,
                public buttons?: DialogResult[]) {
    }

    public showDialog(): Q.Promise<DialogResult> {
        this.deferred = Q.defer<DialogResult>();

        // My logic for displaying the box goes here

        return this.deferred.promise;
    }

    public setResult(result: DialogResult) {
        this.deferred.resolve(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Check out the source for ngDialog. It has an implementation of a promise based dialog. https://github.com/likeastore/ngDialog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd either use a [deferred](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#qdefer) that is stored as a private field of your class, or you'd use the [`Promise` constructor](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#qpromiseresolver) (which is preferred).

```
private deferred : Q.Deferred<DialogResult>; 

public showDialog() : Q.Promise<DialogResult>{
    this.deferred = Q.defer();
    // create dialog
    return this.deferred.promise;
}

public void setResult(result : DialogResult){
    this.deferred.resolve(result);
}
```

```
public showDialog() : Q.Promise<DialogResult>{
    return new Q.Promise(function(resolve) {
        // create dialog

        setResult = resolve;
        // call it somewhere
    })
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Why is the promise ctor preferred?

Comment: It's less verbose without introducing that extra Deferred object. Also, it automatically rejects the promise if the callback function (to `Promise()`, i.e. the one that creates the dialog and sets up the async listeners) throws.

Comment: To be fair, if you assign it to `setResult` as shown here you don't really get a good guarantee and a deferred is as good. On the other hand putting the logic of resolving inside the constructor would work.

Comment: The assignment of `resolve` to `setResult` is only to show that just `resolve` should be called instead of the private `setResult` method.